# Spring boot hibernate types exception creating table with JSON field

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need mysql table with JSON column and therefor I used s vladmihalcea/hibernate-types dependency and I followed official documentation and did the example as its but I got exception and how can I overcome this exception.

> Error executing DDL "create table book (id bigint not null, isbn
> varchar(255), properties jsonb, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via
> JDBC Statement
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'jsonb, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB' at line 1

Entity Class(I have committed getters and setters for clearly show code here and getters and setters should be added)

```
@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String properties;
    
}
```

Repository Interface

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fixed exception by changing

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
```

instead of

```
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
```

Also

```
 @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String properties;
```

instead of

```
 @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String properties;
```

I did mistake and I followed PostgreSQL code example rather than mysql

Comment: I am curious to know how it can work. MySQL does not have a jsonb data type. If you execute this: `create table book (
       id bigint not null,
        isbn_string varchar(255),
        properties jsonb,
        primary key (id)
    )`, you will get an error.

Comment: @jumping_monkey I made a mistake and update the code section.

Comment: Ok, yea thanks for updating, with json, it will work as it's a supported native data type. Cheers.